# MySQL databases irrecoverable after system reboot

Tags: mysql, innodb

We had a power cycle in our lab, and our mysql server restarted.

It seems that the system created a tar ball of my mysql data folder, then un-tarred it. Or in some other way, tried to 'recover' and really messed things up.

Now I cant access any of my tables "table __ does not exist".

All the necessary files (frm, idb etc) seem to be there and of the correct size (quite large).

Unfortunately I am no DB admin and do not have backups.

From searching around on the webz, it seems there is nothing to do but start from scratch, but I find this quite hard to believe, that mysql could mess up 100+ tables  in 1 single operation.

Any help is much appreciated.

All the permissions are correct (I think), and mysqlcheck has not helped

Here are some log exerpts from when I believe the error occured (timestamp is screwey i believe cause of the power outage)

```
070102  2:13:07 [Warning] The syntax '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--general-log'/'--general-log-file' instead.
070102  2:13:07 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
070102  2:13:07 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
070102  2:13:07 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
070102  2:13:07 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
070102  2:13:07 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file /test_results/mysql/innodata/ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
070102  2:13:08  InnoDB: Setting file /test_results/mysql/innodata/ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
070102  2:13:08  InnoDB: Log file /test_results/mysql/innolog/ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file /test_results/mysql/innolog/ib_logfile0 size to 64 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
070102  2:13:08  InnoDB: Log file /test_results/mysql/innolog/ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file /test_results/mysql/innolog/ib_logfile1 size to 64 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
070102  2:13:09  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
070102  2:13:10 InnoDB: 5.5.34 started; log sequence number 0
070102  2:13:10 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
070102  2:13:10 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
070102  2:13:10 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
070102  2:13:11 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
070102  2:13:11 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

Comment: `do not have backups` Make sure you or someone in your lab learns how to create a regular backup schedule. `I find this quite hard to believe, that mysql could mess up 100+ tables in 1 single operation` MySQL didn't do that, but damage to your drives due to sudden power outage could. The tar/untar could be from some sort of script that runs on boot (failed attempt at backup script?). If the tables are missing and you don't have a backup, I don't see any option to recover the DB. Consider adding a UPS to mitigate the impact of power outages.

Comment: Do you still have this mysteriously generated tarball? If so unpack it **somewhere other than the \data folder** and see what is actually in it. You may just get lucky. But I dont believe there is any way that MYSQL just did this for the hell of it!

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I do, tried untarring to a new dir  to re-create to no avail

Comment: So out of interest, what was in it?

Comment: Also do you have the MYSQL log files, if you show us those maybe we can make some sort of suggestion. Only the log record for the time on question, not the whole file which I assume contains weeks/month/years of logs

Comment: @RiggsFolly mysql logs dont show anything, just a bunch of rollbacks

Comment: Your data is stored in `ibdata1` and the schema are in a directory named after the database. There are two logfiles named `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile` that you can safely delete (may lose most recent transactions). Startup mysql. These 2 log files will be auto re-created.

Comment: Those __just a bunch of rollbacks__ could  be useful to know about. Recovering a INNODB database can be a little complicated if you have not done it before. **PS** dont delete the `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile`, move them somewhere out of the data folder but dont delete them they may come in handy

Comment: @RiggsFolly they were all the Same select statement (something our system frequently runs)

Comment: There must have been something reported from MYSQL's attempt to restart and recover

Comment: Actually thinking about it, if you are seeing queries logged, you may be looking in the wrong log file. That sounds like the `general log` and not the `mysql.log` Not sure what it is called on a unix system

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was confused by a bad timestamp, put some logs above. Looks like some crucial files might have gone away :( PS really appreciate youre help

Comment: This `InnoDB: The first specified data file /test_results/mysql/innodata/ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!` means that you lost the data if we are looking at the right log. Notice it says a new database is created?

Comment: It's possible you are attempting to start mysql with a wrong configuration and therefore it points to the wrong data location. Check `/etc/my.cnf` and make sure it points to the right location of your data.

Comment: Is that from the TOP of the `mysql.log` file? If so we need to see the bottom of the file i.e. the last few things it did, that looks like an initial startup i.e. when you fired all this up in 2002

Comment: @RiggsFolly Timestamp is incorrect, the log above it shows a log from a DB I created a month or so ago

Comment: If that is all that is in the log then either some files were missing like you said or @alvits may be on the right lines, and when you started everything up, it has used a different config and that was pointing to a different folder for the `datadir=` in which case your database may exist intact somewhere else on your disc

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first tip, it sounds odd, but fire up a copy of MySQLWorkbench. Open an instance of the administrator and shutdown MySQL. Once it's shutdown, start it back up again.

Now try to access your database.